# Relay request for payment to PayPal via intermediate API

Tags: php, paypal

I have a built a REST service in PHP for a number of client applications to consume. One of the requirements at the service is to process payments for products sold at the client applications.  I assume I would need to retrieve the authorisation URL from PayPal and forward this to the client applications to redirect to and then receive an authorisation code/token back which the REST service can then validate with PayPal. Does anyone know of any examples that implement PayPal in this way?

Comment: Who is the merchant (as far as Paypal is concerned)? That is "who" needs to authenticate.

Comment: Thanks @EdSF. The API would be the merchant but it would need to facilitate payment for products sold at the consuming client end. I have done some further research and it looks like Instant Payment Notifications are the way forward and my "relay" approach is off. I will write up an answer if/when i get something working